# regex stop continuous match when reach specific symbol

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-replace

I want to remove character other than letters and number between two symbol which are `<` and `>` with empty string. The string is `<F=*A*B*C*>`

```
 (?<=F=|\G(?!^))[A-Za-z1-9]*\K[^A-Za-z1-9]+

 //output:<F=ABC 

 (?:^<F=(?=.+>$)|\G(?!^))[A-Za-z1-9]*\K[^A-Za-z1-9]+
 
 //output:<F=ABC
```

This regex pattern capture last closing tag too and removed it (`<F=ABC`). How to make it stop at specific symbol and avoid it from capture last closing tag.

When I add `>` in `[^A-Za-z1-9]`, it can remove characters other than `>` symbol correctly.

```
(?<=F=|\G(?!^))[A-Za-z1-9]*\K[^A-Za-z1-9>]+

//output: <F=ABC>// desired result
```

what is correct way to define stop matching start from this symbol? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|<F=)[^<>]*?\K[^A-Za-z0-9<>]+(?=[^<>]*>)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lobiiG/1).

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|<F=)` - either the end of the previous match or `<F=` text
- `[^<>]*?` - any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>`, as few as possible
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `[^A-Za-z0-9<>]+` - one or more chars other than ASCII letters/digits and `<` and `>` chars
- `(?=[^<>]*>)` - immiediately on the right, there must be zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` and then a `>` char.